# Python How replace non numeric values in a column when it should be only numeric

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace, regexp-replace

## Python How replace non numeric values in a column when it should be only numeric

the goal is to find all the non numeric values in the column ["campaignid"] and attribute a numeric value for them.

```
dataframe:


2790    8/31/2019   143679198                   
2791    8/10/2019   143679198       
2792    8/10/2019   brand           
2793    8/10/2019   brand   
2794    8/10/2019   143679198
2795    8/10/2019   site
2796    8/10/2019   site
```

## My attempts

```
cw= cw["campaignid"].replace(cw["campaignid"]({'brand': "283494005"}), inplace=True)

#error: NoneType' object is not subscriptable



# Tried with for loop as well, but isnt replacing it.

count= 0

for x in cw.campaignid:

    if x == "brand":
        x = "283494005"
        print(f"brand now is.. {x}")


    elif x == "site":
        x = "283494007"
        print(f"site now is.. {x}")


    else:
        count+= 1
```

## Desired result

oNLY NUMERIC VALUES

```
2790    8/31/2019   143679198                   
2791    8/10/2019   143679198       
2792    8/10/2019   283494005
2793    8/10/2019   283494005
2794    8/10/2019   143679198
2795    8/10/2019   283494007
2796    8/10/2019   283494007
```

Comment: `cw["campaignid"]=cw["campaignid"].replace({'brand':283494005,'site':283494007}).astype(int)` ?

Comment: Works!! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
cw["campaignid"]=cw["campaignid"].replace({'brand':283494005,'site':283494007}).astype(int)
```